# Disabled UITextView shows empty context menu on long press

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextView subclass where I specifically disable all context menu options:

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

I add an instance of `MyTextView` to a view that shows up in my app. I give the instance of `MyTextView` the following value: `isEditable = false`

When I long press on the UITextView however, I get the following:

[image]

This seems like a bug since there is nothing in this menu? Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `selectable` property is active. So you can "select" a part of text and iOS default behaviour is to show this popover.

You can disable this property by storyboard, or by code.

Storyboard:
At storyboard, select the textview and go to attribute inspector tab... Search for `behavior` and uncheck `selectable` checkbox.

or, if you prefer, you can solve it by code:
at viewDidLoad method, set the property `isSelectable` to `false`.

```
MyTextView.isSelectable = false
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not "the menu". It's just the thing that magnifies the region where the press occurs:

[image]

It's empty in your screen shot only because you've no text, so we're magnifying nothing. The menu appears after your long press ends and the magnifier thing goes away — and it *doesn't* appear, so your code is working fine.

You can see easily that that's true by changing your code to return `true`. The empty magnifier will appear, just as it does now, and *then* when it disappears, the menu appears. Thus, we have proved that what you are seeing is not "the menu".

Comment: Thank you for this response. Definitely clarified what that control is!